Не работает код на показ курсора C#, Unity 3D
Всем привет, делаю игру на ПК в 3Д, шутер, есть два скрипта PlayerController, и ExitToMenu
в первом задается управление игроком, в том числе и видимость курсора(false)
private void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

Во втором же при нажатии Esc будет перекидываться в новую сцену сделанную для меню игры,но курсор не возвращается, я написал так чтобы при выходе курсор возвращался, но это не работает( В билде тоже )
{
    public void Exit()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = true;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
       {
           Exit();
       }
      
      
    }
}

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем дело

Так вы сначала курсор возвращайте, а потом сцену грузите, а не наоборот.
public void Exit()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}


Да, спасибо, я уже понял, починил, все работает
